# Selenium not closing the command window after executing the tests in IE

Tags: maven-2, selenium, selenium-rc, selenium-webdriver, junit4

we are using maven bases selenium project to test the GUI. After executing the test, IE is not able to close the selenium command window. we are using `selenium.stop();` in `@After` method but it is not closing the command window even the test case is passed.

Hence more browser sessions are opening up and server is going out of resource and not  responding for more time. Most of the test cases are failing because of this.

Since one week we are facing the issue. please help me in solving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Plain guess: Did you try

```
selenium.close();
```

in your `@After` section?

From the javadoc:

public void close()

Simulates the user clicking the "close" button in the titlebar of a popup window or tab.

Comment: darn, I am messing the WebDriver Approach and Selenium RC Approach AGAIN... Will probably not work, sorry